# What's the meaning of suffix icons in Android Studio autocomplete feature?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

**Screenshot:**

[image: auto]

What does

`p`, `f` and `m` mean in the given image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` is for *Property*

`f` is for *Field*

`m` is for *Method*

([source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html))

Comment: Thank you, and what's the difference between `field` and `property`? I thought both are instance variable, aren't they?

Comment: @iKeepChangingName the main difference is in their intended scope. Field is private without getters/setters access. Property is public and usually comes with a combination of getters/setters.